# htaccess rewriting with url removal

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to forward requests from `/bar/baz` to `/web/index.php/bar/baz` so that you do not have to use that "web" folder in the URL. So far I have `/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/index.php [QSA,L]
```

The problem it has is that now the request to `/controller/action/` causes an error:

> No route found for "GET /web/controller/action"

The framework behind this does not matter, the point is that it should be `controller/action` without the additional "web" in the URL.

Comment: Yes, oh **yes** the framework does matter, because it could do a redirect (Wordpress does this on some configuration, Drupal too, and Joomla too). So you have to precise which framework, what URLs should the user type and how it should be internally modified on the server side.

Comment: I'm sorry to be *that* straightforward, but asking for help without giving enough information is sometimes... frustrating.

Comment: @OlivierPons I'm not sure what else can I say? This is all about `.htaccess` and URL rewriting. Rewrite `/web/bar` to `/bar`so that the request URL does not contain `web` part. Right now it does that, but REQUEST_URI still contains the "web".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your .htaccess code with this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(?!web/index\.php|controller/)(.*)$ web/index.php/$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

What this rule will do to internally redirect all the requests except that starting with `/controller` or `/web/index.php` to `/web/index.php`.